# Why doesn't read_line mutate its argument?

Tags: rust

```
fn main() {
    let mut input = String::new();

    loop {
        std::io::stdin()
            .read_line(&mut input)
            .expect("error: unable to read user input");

        println!("input is: {}", input);
    }
}
```

When I first enter `hello` it will show `input is: hello`, then no matter what I enter later it will always show `input is: hello`, so `read_line` doesn't mutate the `input` variable. Why does this happen?

Comment: It appends line inputs  to the buffer you provide, are you sure it just prints only `input is: hello`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`read_line` does mutate the `input` variable, but it does so by appending to it, not overwriting it. If you'd like to overwrite `input` you should first `clear` it before passing it to `read_line` which will give you the behavior you're looking for:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut input = String::new();

    loop {
        input.clear(); // truncate string contents
        std::io::stdin()
            .read_line(&mut input)
            .expect("error: unable to read user input");

        println!("input is: {}", input);
    }
}
```